# Different buttons to pass intent of mp3 files pulled from zip expansion files to a media player

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, android-mediaplayer, apk-expansion-files

I am working on an education app and the expansion files have messed up my thinking a bit.

I have different buttons (a lot of them) in a RelativeLayout. Each display a sentence. When you click on one, it opens up a popup window, in which you have the option to play the mp3 file of the sentence that has opened the popup. It has been all okay, until I was forced to use expansion files.

So, each button click has to pass on an intent of a different audio file that it calls from the expansion file zip package.
I have implemented the zip_file package in the app and I have put the uncompressed zip and (just in case) an obb files on the memory card into an obb folder to be able to test it.

Here are a few sample lines from my original code.

```
final Button btn_L1R_en_L2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_L1R_en_L2);
btn_L1R_en_L2.setOnClickListener(this);
final Button btn_L1R_en_L6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_L1R_en_L6);
btn_L1R_en_L6.setOnClickListener(this);
final Button btn_L1R_en_L7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_L1R_en_L7);
btn_L1R_en_L7.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_L1R_en_L2:
            if (popUpScreen != null && popUpScreen.isShowing()) {
                popUpScreen.dismiss();
                popUpScreen = null;
            } else {
                setEngSent(R.string.lesson1reading_en_L2);
                setFrnSent(R.string.lesson1reading_frn_L2);
                setDfAccSentAudio(R.raw.l1r_df_l2); //originally this is an audio file that the player would need to play, but from now on it has to come from the zip package. How?
                initiatePopupScreen();
            }
        break;

        case R.id.btn_L1R_en_L6:
            if (popUpScreen != null && popUpScreen.isShowing()) {
                popUpScreen.dismiss();
                popUpScreen = null;
            } else {
                setEngSent(R.string.lesson1reading_en_L6);
                setFrnSent(R.string.lesson1reading_frn_L6);
                setDfAccSentAudio(R.raw.l1r_df_l6); //originally this is an audio file that the player would need to play, but from now on it has to come from the zip package. How?
                initiatePopupScreen();
            }
        break;

        case R.id.btn_L1R_en_L7:
            if (popUpScreen != null && popUpScreen.isShowing()) {
                popUpScreen.dismiss();
                popUpScreen = null;
            } else {
                setEngSent(R.string.lesson1reading_en_L7);
                setFrnSent(R.string.lesson1reading_frn_L7);
                setDfAccSentAudio(R.raw.l1r_df_l7);
                initiatePopupScreen();
            }
        break;
    }
}

public void setDfAccSentAudio(int dfAccSentAudio) {
    this.dfAccSentAudio = dfAccSentAudio;
    sentencePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, dfAccSentAudio);
}

btn_default_acc = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_df_acc);
    btn_default_acc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pauseWholeTextPlayer();
            stopSentencePlayer();
            sentencePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Lesson1Reading.this, dfAccSentAudio);
            sentencePlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: What should I put instead of **R.raw.l1r_df_l2**, **R.raw.l1r_df_l6**, and **R.raw.l1r_df_l7** to be able to play them from the zip extension file? At the moment they are coming from the raw folder, but since I have to use extension files that is no longer the case. How should I modify my code to be able to use those same files from the extension file instead of the raw folder? Thanks